# Sparx Enterprise Architect baseline defaults to local temp directory

Tags: enterprise-architect, baseline

I am using Sparx Enterprise Architect with a SQL Server Repository. We wish to take baselines in order to manage change and be able to compare packages and be able to revert to a previous baseline. When using the baseline facility the baseline is saved to a local temporary folder, this means that other users of the repository cannot see or access these local baselines. We have user authentication turned on.

How can I change the default directory the baseline is being saved to? I have searched the EA menus, Sparx documentation and the internet for a way of doing this and come up with nothing. Or alternatively, is there a way for the baselines to be saved in the repository itself so all can access them?

We could use the export to XMI function but it seems to me the baseline was created to be able to do what we want without this.

Location baseline saved to by default:

[image]

Comment: Baselines are part of the repository and stored in the table t_document.

Comment: And the dialog you show is for exporting a package to XMII. So that does not fit your question.

Comment: @Thomas Killan The dialogue shown came up automatically when I used the Package Control > Package Baselines and then clicked on the New Baseline button. This is why I want to know how I can change this behaviour because in the set up I am using it saves it locally as shown above. I managed to grab the dialogue picture above as it flashed up. Or are you saying that as well as this local copy the baseline will have been saved in the database?

Comment: @Thomas Killan Thanks for your help, the penny dropped :-). I have just run a query against t_document and have found the baseline stored in there with the appropriate time.